# Expectation of a conditional variance

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, variance

I have to prove this $$E(Var(Y|X))=(1-\rho^2)Var(Y)$$ but I got stuck and don't know how to continue.

This is what I've done so far based on this variance formula $Var(Y)=E(Var(Y|X))+ Var(E(Y|X))$

$$Var(Y|X)= E(Y^2|X)- (E(Y|X))^2$$
$$=Var(Y)- Var(E(Y|X))$$
$$=Cov(Y,Y)- E(E(Y|X))^2- E(Y)^2$$
I get to the part when I relate the covariance in order to get the correlation coefficient, but I don't know what to do from there, or maybe what I've done is wrong, so I'll be grateful if any of you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's work from your decomposition formula (the "law of total variance"): $$\mathrm{Var}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(\mathrm{Var}(Y|X)) + \mathrm{Var}(\mathbb{E}(Y|X))$$
Rearranging this, you get
$$\mathrm{Var}(Y)\bigg(1 - \frac{\mathrm{Var}(\mathbb{E}(Y|X))}{\mathrm{Var}(Y)}\bigg) = \mathbb{E}(\mathrm{Var}(Y|X)).$$
So you really just need to show that $\mathrm{Var}(\mathbb{E}(Y|X))\big/\mathrm{Var}(Y) = \rho^2$. Try working this out from here.

Comment: I've been trying to show what you've said, but it just leads me to circular references. Trying to prove using this $Var(E(Y|X)Var(x)=(Cov(X,Y)^2)$, expanding both and looking for similar terms to get the equality.

Comment: @karl_jimbo yeah that is non trivial

Answer (score 1):

The identity is false.  I generated a random distribution on $\{\, 0, 1, 2\,\}^2$ to get a case where it is not satisfied. However, we do have the inequality $E[\operatorname{Var} (Y\mid X)] \leqslant (1 -\rho^2) \operatorname{Var}(Y)$.

Since $E[\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X)] = \operatorname{Var}(Y) -\operatorname{Var}(E[Y\mid X])$, it would suffice to show that
$$
\operatorname{Var}(E[Y\mid X])\geqslant \rho^2 \operatorname{Var}(Y).
$$

This inequality can be rewritten as $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)^2\leqslant \operatorname{Var}(X) \operatorname{Var}(E[Y\mid X])$, which follows from Cauchy-Schwarz and the identity $\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) = \operatorname{Cov}(X, E[Y\mid X])$.

Comment: Here is a better counterexample to equality.  Let  X  be uniform on  {0, 1, 2}  and  Y = X^2.  Then  Var(Y | X) = 0,  |$\rho$| < 1  and  Var(X) > 0.

Comment: And an examination of the proof shows that equality holds only when  E[Y | X]  is an affine function of  X  (i.e., a + bX).

Comment: In my first comment, that should be Var(Y) > 0.

Comment: I have rolled back this answer to the 4th revision (see the edit history).  This version of the post is vastly more readable, as it uses correct MathJax formatting.  If the mathematical content of this revision is incorrect, please make further edits which correct any errors without destroying the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

We consider the case where $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal with correlation $\rho$ $(|\rho|<1)$. Let
\begin{align*}
Z = \frac{\frac{Y-E(Y)}{\sqrt{Var(Y)}}-\rho \frac{X-E(X)}{\sqrt{Var(X)}}}{\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}.
\end{align*}
Then $Z$ is also normal and independent of $X-E(X)$, as they are jointly normal with zero correlation. Since 
\begin{align*}
Y=\sqrt{Var(Y)}\left(\sqrt{1-\rho^2} Z + \rho \frac{X-E(X)}{\sqrt{Var(X)}}\right) + E(Y),
\end{align*}
we conclude that
\begin{align*}
E(Y\mid X) = \rho \sqrt{Var(Y)}\frac{X-E(X)}{\sqrt{Var(X)}} + E(Y).
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
Var\big(E(Y\mid X)\big) = \rho^2\, Var(X)\,Var(Y),
\end{align*}
and, consequently,
\begin{align*}
E\big(Var(Y\mid X)\big)=\left(1-\rho^2\right)Var(Y).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

As for the useful identity aforementioned by Herschkorn, namely
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y) = \operatorname{Cov}(X, E[Y\mid X]),
$$
it follows from the definition of the covariance, by means of the law of total expectation:
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)
&= E[XY] - E[X]\, E[Y]\\
&= E[E[XY\mid X]] - E[X]\cdot E[E[Y\mid X]]\\
&= E[X\cdot E[Y\mid X]] - E[X]\cdot E[E[Y\mid X]]\\
&= \operatorname{Cov}(X, E[Y\mid X]).
\end{align}