# Expected value of a conditional variance.

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with $p$ as correlation coefficient. Prove that:
>   $$E(Var(Y|X))=(1-p^2)Var(Y)$$

So I've tried two different ways but with a dead end for me:

1. $Var(Y)(1-p^2)= \left(1-\left(\frac{Cov(X,Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)}\sqrt{Var(Y)}}\right)^2\right)Var(Y)= Var(Y)-\frac{(Cov(X,Y))^2}{Var(X)}$
2. $E(Var(Y|X))=E(E(Y^2|X)-(E(Y|X))^2)=E(Y^2)-E((E(Y|X))^2)$

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that $E(Y|X)$ is a linear function of $X$?

Comment: I think there were some typos. Please verify my edit. Also, this there any additional information on $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: Does $Y$ follow a Normal distribution given $X$?

Comment: It appears a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281958/expectation-of-a-conditional-variance/2283862#2283862).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that some more detail is missing about $X$ and $Y$ (e.g. if they are jointly normal, or as pointed out in the comments if a linear estimation of $E(Y|X)$ is sought). Under such assumption we can do as follows:

The [law of total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance) is:

$$Var(Y)=E(Var(Y|X))+Var(E(Y|X))$$
Thus
$$E(Var(Y|X))=Var(Y)-Var(E(Y|X))$$
Now it suffices to prove that $Var(E(Y|X))=p^2Var(Y)$.

If $Y$ is normally distributed given $X$, then $E(Y|X)$ would be linear in $X$ and using regression equation is given by
$$E(Y|X)=EX+p\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}(X-EX)$$ which yields $$Var(E(Y|X))=p^2 \frac{Var(Y)}{Var(X)}Var(X)=p^2Var(Y)$$